# I have a diagram of the complex plane, but I want an error margin in magnitude

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a particular system that supplies a signal
that has to be decoded as an integer for a full circle in the range 0..1799.

[image: complex plane angles mapped to modulo 1800 integer]
I also have a margin of error.
How can I modify this picture to show a 1.5 \pm 0.25
magnitude circle where the 
value is acceptable, but also indicate that
the area outside of that is not.

Here is the tikz code I am currently using, where the edge
of the grey area represents the ideal value.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize]
    % Axes:
    % Are simply drawn using line with the `->` option to make them arrows:
    % The main labels of the axes can be places using `node`s:
    \draw [->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node [above left]  {$\Re\{z\}$};
    \draw [->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node [below right] {$\Im\{z\}$};

    % Axes labels:
    % Are drawn using small lines and labeled with `node`s. The placement can be set using options
    \iffalse% Single
    % If you only want a single label per axis side:
    \draw (1,-3pt) -- (1,3pt)   node [above] {$1$};
    \draw (-1,-3pt) -- (-1,3pt) node [above] {$-1$};
    \draw (-3pt,1) -- (3pt,1)   node [right] {$i$};
    \draw (-3pt,-1) -- (3pt,-1) node [right] {$-i$};
    \else% Multiple
    % If you want labels at every unit step:
    \foreach \n in {-1.5,...,-1.0,1.0,1.0,...,-1.5}{%
        \draw (\n,-3pt) -- (\n,3pt)   node [above] {$\n$};
        \draw (-3pt,\n) -- (3pt,\n)   node [right] {$\n i$};
    }
    \fi
    \end{scope}
    % The circle is drawn with `(x,y) circle (radius)`
    % You can draw the outer border and fill the inner area differently.
    % Here I use gray, semitransparent filling to not cover the axes below the circle
    \path [draw=none,fill=gray,semitransparent] (+0,0) circle (1.5);
    % Place the equation into the circle:
    \node [above right,red] at (+2,0) {$\alpha = 0 \; or \; \alpha = 1800$};
    \node [above right,blue] at (+2,-0.3) {$0 \; or \; 2 \pi \; radians $};

\node [above right,red] at (0,2) {$\alpha = 450$};
\node [below right,blue] at (0,2.9) {$\frac{\pi}{2} \; radians$};


\node [below right,red] at (-4.4,0.4) {$\alpha = 900$};
\node [below right,blue] at (-4.4,0.1) {$ {\pi} \; or -{\pi} \; radians$};


\node [below right,red] at (0,-2) {$\alpha = 1350$};
\node [below right,blue] at (0,-2.3) {$-\frac{\pi}{2} \; radians$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:zplane} always put the label at the end!
\caption{
%
Amplified voltages interpreted as complex numbers; the angle in radians
is converted to a modulo 1800 integer used to represent a rotation. 
%
Note the integer
increments in same direction to the angles in radians if the servo angle
is viewed from the front (i.e. facing the shaft). 
%
The magnitude, typically $1V5 ... 1V58$, is shown as the edge of the grey area.}
\label{fig:zplane}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: If you want a ring, just do `\path [draw=none,fill=gray,semitransparent,even odd rule] (+0,0) circle (1.5) circle (1);`. Or are you asking for advice how to indicate the allowed region?

Comment: Thats a good idea, but, yes as well, is there a convention to indicate the allowed region?

Comment: Well, there is not "a convention" but unfortunately there are tons of them such that in the end you have to make your own choice. To me the ring looks good as long as you indicate in the caption or text that it marks the allowed region.

Comment: OK I have gone with a semi transparent blue  circle '\pm' 0.25V for the allowed region. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be happy to remove this, but here comes a way to draw the ring, i.e. the "allowed" region, plus some additional minor changes (text in text mode etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize]
    % Axes:
    % Are simply drawn using line with the `->` option to make them arrows:
    % The main labels of the axes can be places using `node`s:
    \draw [->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node [above left]  {$\re z$};
    \draw [->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node [below right] {$\im z$};

    % Axes labels:
    % Are drawn using small lines and labeled with `node`s. The placement can be set using options
    \iffalse% Single
    % If you only want a single label per axis side:
    \draw (1,-3pt) -- (1,3pt)   node [above] {$1$};
    \draw (-1,-3pt) -- (-1,3pt) node [above] {$-1$};
    \draw (-3pt,1) -- (3pt,1)   node [right] {$\mathrm{i}$};
    \draw (-3pt,-1) -- (3pt,-1) node [right] {$-\mathrm{i}$};
    \else% Multiple
    % If you want labels at every unit step:
    \foreach \n in {-1.5,...,-1.0,1.0,1.0,...,-1.5}{%
        \draw (\n,-3pt) -- (\n,3pt)   node [above] {$\n$};
        \draw (-3pt,\n) -- (3pt,\n)   node [right] {$\n \mathrm{i}$};
    }
    \fi
    \end{scope}
    % The circle is drawn with `(x,y) circle (radius)`
    % You can draw the outer border and fill the inner area differently.
    % Here I use gray, semitransparent filling to not cover the axes below the circle
    \path [draw=none,fill=gray,semitransparent,even odd rule] (+0,0) circle (1.5) circle (1);
    % Place the equation into the circle:
    \node [above right,red] at (+2,0) {$\alpha = 0$ or $\alpha = 1800$};
    \node [above right,blue] at (+2,-0.3) {$0$ or $2 \pi$ radians};

    \node [above right,red] at (0,2) {$\alpha = 450$};
    \node [below right,blue] at (0,2.9) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians};


    \node [below right,red] at (-4.4,0.4) {$\alpha = 900$};
    \node [below right,blue] at (-4.4,0.1) {$ {\pi}$ or ${\pi}$ radians};


    \node [below right,red] at (0,-2) {$\alpha = 1350$};
    \node [below right,blue] at (0,-2.3) {$-\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:zplane} always put the label at the end!
\caption{
%
Amplified voltages interpreted as complex numbers; the angle in radians
is converted to a modulo 1800 integer used to represent a rotation. 
%
Note the integer
increments in same direction to the angles in radians if the servo angle
is viewed from the front (i.e.\ facing the shaft). 
%
The magnitude, typically $1V5 \ldots 1V58$, is shown as the edge of the grey area.}
\label{fig:zplane}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]